# Difficulty resizing a partition

Tags: partitioning, easeus-partition-manager

I have a 320GB Hard Drive

If I click on the drive in Easeus and "View Properties" I think it shows me the partition information

```
Easeus View Properties
  Used 13.3GB   97%
  Unused  376MB  3%
  Total  13.7GB  100%
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmKIk.png)
[image]

Here is how disk management reports it

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwNTn.png)
[image]
OK

Here is how Easeus reports it

[image]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUiv7.png)

OK

But I find myself unable to resize the partition. The partition seems to be 13GB and only a few hundred MB free on the partition .and it's a 320GB drive. So I want to resize the partition.  But notice now Easeus makes it look like the partition is 320GB.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFcDo.png)

According to [Easeeus's help](http://www.partition-tool.com/easeus-partition-manager/help/resizing-and-moving-partition.htm), you're meant to expand it to the right

but there is no room to in the picture of what I see. 
[image]

Comment: I have not been rigorous here to see when it's talking of partition  size and when it's talking of disk size. The info above looking at it it isn't clear that it even conflicts.  The mystery is that Easeus in one window has the partition size (F) as 13GB, and another window shows it as already resized. Maybe it means as a task that was requested, the partition has already been resized. And so the window showing the partition as 13GB meant it is. And the resize window was about how you want it, and maybe you had already said you want it as 300ishGB.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164818/resize-partition-after-image-using-dd-to-another-drive   `resize_reiserfs /dev/sda4`  (though reiserf is not ntfs) and https://learninginlinux.wordpress.com/tag/resize_reiserfs/ says you run that resize line then fdisk then the resize line again, but no doubt the resize line is slightly different for ntfs

Answer (score -1):

The partition is corrupt  (in my case not done right)

This can be determined, by looking at the claimed size of the partition, the amount used and the amount remaining.

The claimed size of the partition is 320GB, the size of the drive.

The amount used on the drive or partition, is 13GB.

So there should be lots of space left, not just a few hundred megabytes.

I managed to resize it in Paragon to about 195GB but it is still corrupt and this can be shown in a similar manner.

The claimed size was 195GB.

This time, the amount remaining was 195GB. So that wasn't right as I was using 13GB.

So definitely partition was not done right, and that is the or a sign of it.

Comment: If things are corrupt, just backup the data, delete everything and create a new partition table and partition as needed. Anything else could potentially leave you in an unknown state that could cause problems immediately, or later on down the road.